# Changing display resolution for Yosemite guest OS in VMware Fusion

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, vmware-fusion

I have Yosemite as the guest OS (and host OS) version 10.10.3 and VMware Fusion 7.1.1.

When I start Yosemite in VMware Fusion as a guest its display resolution is 1024x768 and I cannot change it!  I looked in System Preferences under display (in the guest OS) and I looked at VM settings for the guest in VMware Fusion.  Neither place gives the option to change the resolution.

Here's a screen shot of the options in the guest OS:
[image]

Here's a screenshot of the options in the VM settings:
[image]

I've tried selecting "Scaled" in the guest and there is one option: 1024x768.  I tried with and without "Use full resolution for Retina display" in the VM settings.

How do I change the resolution?

Answer (score 1):

Install VMSVGA II :)

I test it with some success but the dock is gone ! :(

http://www.sysprobs.com/increase-screen-resolution-wide-screen-support-mac-os-virtual-machine-vmware-player-workstation

Comment: Whenever I install this driver, the mac vm starts to crash. It doesn't even show wallpaper. The menus are visible but nothing else.